# Oven racks and heating element

Tags: baking, cake, oven

I read that we should place the cake pan on the middle rack when baking a cake. Since my oven has only 4 racks, I am not sure if I should put my cake pan on the second lowest rack or the second upper rack? The cake I want to bake is Betty Crocker Super Moist white cake.

Also - My oven has no fan inside. I have the option to have a bottom or top heating element. I can even use both the top and bottom heating element at once. So I was wondering which heating element should I use to bake a cake? Top / bottom / top and bottom?

Answer (score 2):

Heat transfer is via

- conduction
- convection
- radiation

You don't have any conduction as you are not touching the heating element

The top element has direct radiant exposure to the cake so it will crust the top surface.  Can use the top element (broil) to brown meat.

From the bottom there is radiant energy to the bottom so that will crust the bottom but to a lower extent as it is shielded by the cake pan.

Convection will provide the most even heat.

On the third rack use a smaller empty pan or baking stone to shield the second from most of radiant heat from the bottom but not block circulation.  Preheat, cook on second shelf, and only use the bottom element.

Answer (score 0):

I finally baked the cake! I used both top and bottom heating element for preheating and only the bottom heating element when baking. I placed the cake pan on the second lower shelf position. It worked well! Thank you for helping :)